# How to send $POST with a link ? with java or anything suitable?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I have created a plugin for wordpress that is to rate comments with star - for make it work I want when somene click on the link it send a veriable through post - I don't know what I am doing wrong please check my code its not redirecting to another page. When I click nothing happens here he code.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function DoPost(){
$.post("Page.php", { star: "John"} );
}
</script>
```

to make it work I am using this hyperlink

```
<a href=javascript:DoPost()>Click Here</a>
```

but when I click it nothing happens ? what am I doing wrong ?

The full code which its under inside a plugin

```
      add_filter('comment_text', 'commentimage_comment_text2');
       function commentimage_comment_text2($comment)
       { ?>

        <script language="javascript"> 
     function DoPost(){
       $.post("Page.php", { star: "John"} );
         }
        </script>

         <?php echo $comment; ?> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DoPost();">Click  Here</a> 
         <?php 
          }
```

The script is working checked by adding

```
  alert('something');
```

on click it is opening a window saying 'something' what' wrong here whats going on ?

Comment: you are calling the `DoPost` method in the wrong way.`href` refers to the location where the link should go. Use `onClick` and call the method

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DoPost();">Click Here</a>
```

OR:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DoPost();">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: You beat me by 50 seconds ;)

Comment: @KellyJames Where did you put you `<script>` code? Did you put any log codes in your `DoPost` function?

Comment: @KellyJames Put some debug lines in `DoPost` function, like `alert('something');` to determine is it running or not?

Comment: yes its working on click it is returing something ? but why its not redirecting to another page ?

Comment: @KellyJames Of course it will no redirect to another page, because it's only an ajax request that posts data to server and gives returned data to you as parameters of `success` callback. Read more in docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/